# Convert polygons, points, lines to GML

Tags: gdal, convert, c++

I've got a vector of points, polygons, and lines. And I'm trying to convert the points into a GML file like a Web Feature Service. I've been doing some reading but can't find any methods that can do this?

I'm coding in C++ with QT

Using GDAL Libraries

Comment: Perhaps http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html and http://www.gdal.org/drv_gml.html could help as a starting point. You can find source code from https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal.

Comment: Show us some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I tried this but it is fairly easy as GML is an output format like any other in OGR. So you should be able to take the tutorial from http://www.gdal.org/ogr_apitut.html and change "ESRI Shapefile" to "GML" compile and run it.

Comment: Okay so from that function which gets my polygons etc. and make it into Gdal structures how do I get the GML returned from that? Because once I've converted it into GML i want to be able to push it onto a WFS.

Comment: If you want to push it into WFS why don't you use some ready made WFS server like GeoServer, MapServer, TinyOWS, QGIS server, or deegree? Do you want to program your own WFS server?

Comment: This is trending to a general how do I program question rather than a specific GIS question. Did you work through the OGR tutorial to find out how it worked?

Comment: Yeah I had a look at that tutorial, its a shame GDAL/OGR documentation hasn't been updated for an age. But I've managed to change the code to match the current version of Gdal. I think that might have to be the solution to have a 3rd party Wfs server.

Comment: At the end of that tutorial, once I've created my data source how would I save that data source to my desktop for example. I've set the driver up to be in GML, and I'm just about to test if it works.